# Implementing Sticky Navbar in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm attempting to create the following layout using a RecyclerView:

[image: On initial layout] 
[image: After scrolling, with Navigation bar stuck to top]

Areas:

1. Header - scrolls off screen.
2. Navigation bar- Scrolls to the top of the screen, then sticks. Contents of Area 3 scroll beneath it.

   A. List button - Displays the contents of 3 as a list.

   B. Grid button - Displays the contents of 3 as a grid.

   C. Info button - Hides the contents of 3, shows a different view.
3. Items - Views displayed as list or grid.

I'm currently using a StaggeredGridLayoutManager which lets me set areas 1 and 2 with a full span and giving me the option of toggling Area 3 to display as a list or as a grid.

How can I implement this concept for the navigation bar? I've tried implementing it as an ItemDecoration, but that blocks the OnClick functionality of the buttons.

Comment: Have you documented how you implemented this using ItemDecoration? I am looking for a similar solution but I don't need click listeners associated with my headers.

As far as your issue, I believe both: 
-https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview
-https://github.com/eowise/recyclerview-stickyheaders
of those libraries allow for click listeners on the header views.

Comment: Both of those allow click listeners on header views, but my "header" is a navigation bar, which needs three separate listeners.

I ended up not using an item decoration, but a separate library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across [SuperSLiM](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM), a layout manager that supports all of this functionality and more. If you are looking to do anything interesting with RecyclerView, I highly suggest you look at this library.